# how to add menu item dynamically in android?

Tags: android, menu

i wrote a small program tp practise adding menu items dynamically according to the offical doc, it just doesn't work:
  the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MenuInflater mi;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.opt, menu);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        menu.addIntentOptions(Menu.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE, 
                              3, 
                              0, 
                              this.getComponentName(),
                              null, 
                              intent,
                              0, 
                              null);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    }    
}
```

and the DestActivity is:

```
public class DestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.app.alex.testadd"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DestActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it, works for me:

```
package com.learn.menu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int UPDATE_DATA = 0;
    private static final int ADD_NEW = 1;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){ 

        menu.add(0,UPDATE_DATA,0,"Update Information");
        menu.add(0,ADD_NEW,1,"Add New Inspection"); 

        return true; 
    } 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
    { 
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
           case(UPDATE_DATA):
               Log.d("tag", "update");
               break;
           case(ADD_NEW):
              Log.d("tag", "Add");
               break; 
          } 
        return false; 
       } 
}
```

Comment: thank you, but the point is how to use the method: addIntentOptions to create cumstomized items